# Assistance with some complex regex. Python 2.7

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I want some assistance with regex. I wrote code to get a word and its meaning and add it to the dictionary. Currently, the regex code I'm using has these features:

```
1- no space at the start of the sentence.
2- no space more than one after a word.
3- letters from a-z and A-Z are allowed.
4- no space at the end of a sentence.
```

The code:

```
while not re.match("^[a-zA-Z_]+( [a-zA-Z_]+)*$",meaning):
```

But, I also want it to allow:

```
1- a "full stop" aka "."
2- "apostrophies" aka '""'
3- and "comma".
```

So the new regex should be for the meaning but for the word I want:

```
1- no space at the start of the sentence.
2- no space more than one after a word.
3- letters from a-z and A-Z are allowed.
4- no space at the end of a sentence.
5- allow a "full stop" aka "."
6- max two words.
```

Please provide me with the two regex's. Thx!

Comment: You need to provide the actual samples.

Comment: I have provided the actual sample which I am using for the word and the meaning. It's with the while loop.

Comment: Actually, you haven't provided any sample. You've provided rules, but no examples. And - where did "6- max two words." come from? Should the sentence contain 2 words at the most?

Answer (score 1):

#### The "word" regex

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z_]+\.?(?: (?!$)|$)){1,2}$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/gZ3cH8/1

Assumptions and notes:

1. The dot may not appear in the middle of a word or at the start of one.
2. The dot may come after the first word even it is followed by another word.

Explanation:

- The outer part: `^(?:...){1,2}$` - ensures the inner part (replaced by ellipsis here) appears only once or twice
- The inner part: `[a-zA-Z_]+\.?(?: (?!$)|$)`:

  - `[a-zA-Z_]+` - a word with punctuation followed by
  - `\.?` - an optional dot and
  - `(?: (?!$)|$)` - a space but only if the space is not immediately followed by the end of line

#### The "meaning" regex

```
^(?:"?[a-zA-Z_]+"?(?:,(?!$)|\.)?(?: (?!$)|$))+$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/yV2uW9/1

Assumptions and notes:

1. The requirement `2- "apostrophies" aka '""'` in contradictory. I take it you need to allow double quotes (`"`) but not apostrophes (`'`).
2. The regex does not check closing quotes match opening ones (balancing groups).
3. Punctuation (quotes, comma and dot) may not appear in the middle of a word or at the start of one.
4. Comma may not appear at the end of line.

Explanation:

- The outer part: `^(?:...)+$` - ensures the inner part (replaced by ellipsis here) appears only one or more times
- The inner part: `"?[a-zA-Z_]+"?(?:,(?!$)|\.)?(?: (?!$)|$)` - a word with puntiation followed by an optional space:

  - `"?` an optional opening quotes
  - `[a-zA-Z_]+` - a word with punctuation followed by
  - `"?` an optional closing quotes and
  - `(?:,(?!$)|\.)?` - an optional comma or dot but the comma should not be immediately followed by the end of line
  - `(?: (?!$)|$)` - a space but only if the space is not immediately followed by the end of line